# Capture different frequencies from an audio?

Tags: c#, windows-8

Do we have any libraries and package files with the help of which I can capture various frequencies in an audio sample?

I want to capture various frequencies within an audio file. Initially, I am concentrating on making it a desktop application for windows 8.

Comment: You looked at NAudio? http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: Are you looking to FFT your audio?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219365/how-to-measure-sound-frequency-using-c-sharp-or-xna

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries that could do that (even if they're not native).
Considering that you're using .NET your best bet would be:

- NAudio http://naudio.codeplex.com/
- BASS.NET http://bass.radio42.com/